# Using jVectormap

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

I am using jVectormap, My client has offices in USA, Netherlands and Singapori. Is there a way to show only these countries on the map and still use markers to show the office locations? the location should be clickable(link) to another page

Answer (score 0):

To show only 3 countries, there are 2 ways.

1. update [jvectormap-world-mill](http://jvectormap.com/js/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill.js), so that it contains only countries you are interested in. In this way, jvector will display only countries you listed. And still you can use markers.
2. Other way is to use standard world map and color countries you are not interested into a white color (or some light grey color). And color the 3 countries into a more contrast color.

Default color is set by:

```
regionStyle: {
 initial: {
  //Default color for countries (light grey)
  fill: '#E5E5E5',
 }
}
```

And color for your interested countries would be:

```
   series: {
    regions: [{
     //Color for Dark countries
     scale: ['#bac0c6', '#9f2742'],
     normalizeFunction: 'linear',
     values: regions.reduce(function(p, c){
      p[c.name] = c.status;
      return p;
     },{}
    ),
   }]
  }
```

and the regions variable is set:

```
var regions = [
 {name: 'AT', status: 0, link:'disable'},
```

I am using the second way at my blog: https://sevenhillsaway.com/map/, so you can take a look at the code if anything is unclear. Point is, I am actually coloring them to 3 colors, that's why I use the reduce function. You can omit that and use easy to assign the value.